# ThrowException does not exists in the current context

Tags: c#, .net

Doing some practice in vs2010.

working with a try/catch/finally and getting the following message:

Throw Exception does not exists in the current context. 
Am I missing a using statement to use the ThrowExcpetion?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static string[] eTypes = { "none", "simple", "index", "nested index" };
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (string eType in eTypes)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Main() try");
                Console.WriteLine("Throwing: \"{0}\") Called.",eType);

                ThrowException(eType);
                Console.WriteLine("Main() try continuing");

            }
            catch (System.IndexOutOfRangeException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Main System.indexoutofrange catch",
                    e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Main finally");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

Comment: What is `ThrowException()`? It's not a built-in method, where do you define it?

Comment: If you're trying to learn how to handle exceptions, then learn to not display ex.Message. Use ex.ToString() to get the entire exception.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have a method named `ThrowException` defined.

If you're trying to raise an exception, that's not how it's done.  You'd do:

```
 throw new SomeTypeOfException(eType);
```

Given your testing, I suspect you want:

```
 throw new IndexOutOfRangeException(eType);
```

For details, see [throw (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ah5wsex.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Its not a function ThrowException().  Its a statement; throw new Exception("some message");

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use

```
throw new Exception(eType);
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for throwing an exception intentionally is simply

```
throw new WhateverException(yourMessage, yourInnerException);
```

The typical exception also has constructor overloads that either accept only the message or no parameters at all.